# Fiori Launchpad - How do you setup a tile to redirect to Business Objects using existing Fiori Credentials?

Tags: sapui5

Is this possible?

The Fiori login credentials are to be use to login to the following URL, via an app Launcher tile.

http://sapvsbiap01:8080/BOE/BILaunchpad

This'll show the users reports.

Comment: It's not possible to pass login credentials from a Fiori Tile to Business Objects. You will have to setup SSO for this

Comment: Is your Fiori Launchpad and Business Objects within the same domain?
What login procedure do you use for Fiori and Business Objects?